# How to find percentage of each box inside a container, knowing the size of the container and the boxes(6)

Tags: html, css, math, responsive-design, responsive

I have 6 boxes that I want to fit inside a container. 
The width of each box is 320px and the container is 1920px.

How do I find out the percentage of each box so this can be responsive? What is the math for this?

Inspiration:
https://www.m2mblue.com/

Thank you.

Comment: Can I recommend dividing 1 by 6?

Comment: You divide the 1920 by 100 to get the amount represented by 1%. That should give you an amount of pixels that equal 1%. Next, you divide the 320 by the amount to see how many time that goes into the the 320. That should be your percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math for this is 100% / 6.

You can use a css rule:

```
.your-div {
width: 16.66%;
}
```

Or:

```
.your-div {
width: calc(100% / 6);
}
```